# Using a comma to avoid using "and"

Tags: grammaticality, commas, conjunctions

In my writing I often use a comma and the past progressive tense (I think) to make sentences more concise.

For example:

> The new design was more intuitive and user-friendly, reducing user errors.

Is this grammatically correct? Are there better alternatives?

Comment: The comma doesn't *avoid using "and"*. Even if you'd used the alternative *"and **reduced** user errors"* it would still be required. It's just that *"reducing"* carries the strong implication the reduction in errors is a *direct consequence* of being more intuitive and user-friendly, rather than simply another characteristic of the new design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is grammatically correct. In fact, replacing the comma with an and will remove the validity of the sentence.

"Reducing user errors" is a phrase. It has no subject, only a verb. This phrase shows another thing that the design does. The main thing the design does is that it is more intuitive and user-friendly. The phrase shows another thing that it does as a result of being more intuitive and user-friendly, in this case. This is a very good sentence. I would say that you continue using this format because it works very well.

Comment: @JohathanSpirit Thanks for your recommendations.  I structure my sentences in this manner very often, so I am glad to here this is grammatically sound.

Comment: You are very welcome. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @kmb385 Before you and Jonathan sign off on this matter, I think you should both take note of Fumble Fingers' comment above.